# Forbidden toroidal minors

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[A finite graph is planar if and only if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem) it does not have $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor. Is there a (finite) set of minors that can classify if a graph is [toroidal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, see [Robertson-Seymour theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem). Additionally

> The complete set of forbidden minors for toroidal graphs remains unknown, but contains at least 16000 graphs.

Comment: Wow, that is a much larger set than I expected! Do you know, off-hand, if there are simple ways to test if a graph is toroidal? If not, I can ask in a new question.

Comment: @Hooked I don't know. I just remembered this theorem and was lucky enough to find that quote in the wikipedia page of it :)

Comment: @Hooked [I answered this question about testing if a graph is toroidal over on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/119493/64073)